# use a table as a border around another table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Trying to create a nice html email with a border around the content, but haven't figure that out.....there is always something..... Thanks for a help!

```html
<table bgcolor="#ACD13C" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Text goes here</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: around what content? every `<td>` ?

Comment: yes, it would go around the whole second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your table in a div, make it's background that green and `width:100%`, change the background of your table to white and its width to `500`, the `margin:0 auto` will center the table, like this:

[**JS Fiddle**- *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2sg3hm9z/2/)

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color:#ACD13C; padding:50px 0; ">
  <table style="margin:0 auto;" bgcolor="white" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Text goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question.. Can you create like 30px bgcolor/border around the second table?

Comment: You welcome, what second table? if you can put your code in a fiddle and I will check it out to see what you mean

Comment: The same code only( div style="width:100%... )to something like width="530" if that's even possible. It would create a small frame not 100%. I can put in a fiddle too if you like.

Comment: sure, you want `30px` on all sides? like top, bottom left and right?

Comment: sure, you can remove the background color of the second container div, and instead add `border:30px solid #ACD13C;` to the second table inline css, just like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hjv97neL/)

Comment: and yeah forgot about the `width="530"` part, yes it is possible https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hjv97neL/1/

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

like this???

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%!important;
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
        }

        .header {
            padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 601px) {
            .content {
                width: 600px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ACD13C" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" bgcolor="#ACD13C">
                            Text goes here
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no. it makes a text green too. It should be like a frame around the newsletter content.

Comment: Thank you Rusdana for your effort!!! I am a newby to the html&css coding.  Do you know if there is any good book to learn about coding? Thanks again and have a good evening.

Comment: Welcome George......http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp is best for html,css even u can go to https://www.codecademy.com/...i hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
td {
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<table bgcolor="#ACD13C" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Text goes here</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not really. It would look like this-http://www.activecampaign.com/blog/author/kvann/ only without top and footer info(first newsletter). Hope this will make more sense. Thank you

Comment: No I still don't get it. Could you provide a more extensive html and an image of what that html should look like?

Comment: Please look at S.Rusdana example and my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

do u want to see like this??

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%!important;
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
        }

        .header {
            padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 601px) {
            .content {
                width: 600px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ACD13C" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            Text goes here
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes! is there an option to have a green on top and bottom too?

Comment: @S.Rusdana, please just update your answer, no need to post a new answer every time you change something, thanks